# Laravel 5.4 pdf generate: Image not found or type unknown in dompdf after download pdf

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5.4

I am trying to generate a pdf using laravel dom pdf. When i download my pdf it does not show my image. It shows Image not found or type unknown. But in browser it shows correctly. I have followed other corresponding questions in stack. I have enabled `$isRemoteEnabled = true;`   How can i resolve this?

This is my pdfview:

```
<html>
    <head>
    {{--<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('css/style.css') }}">--}}
        <style>
            /*pdf view start*/
            .pdf-content{
                /*pdf body*/
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: #d3d3d3;
            }
            .pdf-doctor{
                /*for doctor*/
                border-bottom: 1px dashed gray;
            }
            .rx{
                float: left;
                margin-top: 5px;
                width: 100px;
                height:100px;
            }
            .rx img{
                width: 100px;
                height:100px;
            }
            .doctor-info p{
                text-align: center;
            }
            /*{{--for patient start--}}*/
            .pdf-patient{
                margin-top: 7px;
                border-top: 1px dashed gray;
                height: 30px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .pdf-patient h4{
                float: left;
                display: inline;
                color: #0000cc;
            }
            .pdf-patient-name-date{
                float: left;
                margin-left: 76px;
                margin-top: 7px;
                width: 45%;
            }

            .pdf-test{
                /*for test*/
                margin-top: 50px;
                height: 20em;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .pdf-test h4{
                margin-left: 76px;
                /*display: inline;*/
                color: #0000cc;
            }
            .pdf-test-list{
                border: 1px solid black;
                float: left;
                margin-left: 116px;
                width: 40%;
            }
            .pdf-test-list p{
                margin-left: 15px;
                padding-top: 5px;
            }
            .pdf-test-done{
                border-top: 1px solid black;
                border-right: 1px solid black;
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                float: left;
                /*margin-left: 76px;*/
                /*margin-top: 15px;*/
                height: 37px;
                width: 10%;
            }
            .pdf-comments{
                /*for comment*/
                margin-top: 50px;
                height: 30px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .pdf-comments h3{
                /*for comment*/
                margin-left: 76px;
                /*display: inline;*/
                color: #0000cc;
            }

            /*pdf view end*/
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="pdf-content">
            <div class="pdf-doctor">
                <div class="rx">
                    <img src=" {{ url("/images/rx1.png") }}">
                    {{--{{URL::asset('/image/propic.png')}}--}}
                </div>
                {{--for doctor--}}
                <div class="doctor-info">
                    <p>Doctor's name here</p>
                    <p>Doctor's degree here</p>
                    <p>Doctor's Address here</p>
                    <p>Doctor's Mob here</p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="pdf-patient">
                {{--for patient--}}
                <div class="pdf-patient-name" style="float: left;">
                    <h4 style="display: inline;"><i>Patient name</i>:&nbsp&nbsp</h4>
                    <h4 style="display: inline;">{{ $patients->name }}</h4>
                    {{--style="text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-style: dotted;"--}}
                </div>
                <div class="pdf-patient-date" style="margin-left: 175px;">
                    <h4 style="display: inline;"><i>Date</i>:&nbsp&nbsp</h4>
                    <h4 style="display: inline;">{{ $patients->created_at }}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pdf-test">
                {{--for test--}}
                <h4>Tests</h4>
                <div style="height: 5px;"></div>
                {{--@foreach($patients as $patient)--}}
                <div class="pdf-test-list">
                    <p>{!! nl2br($patients->test) !!}</p>
                </div>
                {{--<div class="pdf-test-done">--}}
                    {{--<p>tik</p>--}}
                {{--</div>--}}
                {{--@endforeach--}}

            </div>
            <div class="pdf-comments">
                {{--for comment--}}
                <h3 >Comments</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my Controller:

```
public function PdfView(Request $request, $patient_id)
{
   $patients = Patient::where('id', $patient_id)->first();
   $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview', ['patients'=>$patients]);
   return $pdf->download('pdfview.pdf');
}
```

my image is in `public/images/rx1.png` and pdfview is in views folder. How can i resolve this?

Comment: IMHO an advice: try to use laravel/snappy from the same author its more powerful with complex layouts respect to DomPDF that is pretty basic.

Comment: @dparoli I used laravel/snappy at first. But it gives me processtimeouterror when i add image, i tried to solve it by increasing timeperiod and follwing https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/issues/169 this link. But could not solve the problem. That's why i am using dompdf now. Can u tell me how can i resolve this in snappy and current problem in dompdf?

Comment: is the image a png? if yes transform it to a jpeg with an editor and change extension accordingly

Comment: @dparoli i transformed it into jpeg as you said, but still it shows same problem.

Comment: last try: use an absolute path instead of a URL for the images in the pdf view only

Comment: @dparoli it works. Thank you :) but why it created problem even if the path was correct?

Comment: URL is for retrieving resources client side, i.e. the browser. Php (and DomPDF library) works server side so it has to know the absolute path to resources.

Comment: @dparoli so when i will retrieve images or other resources from server, not from my local pc or something like this, then i don't need to give absolute path. I just have to give the location normally. Is it right? And at that time can i use any type of image not only .jpeg?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use absolute paths for images, and probably for others resources, like css and javascripts if they are not loaded.

For this its better to have a layout dedicated to pdf export with absolute paths to load resources.

As an alternative you can try to set:

```
isRemoteEnabled: true
```

in config/dompdf.php and use your normal view layout.

Answer (score 0):

Got This issue if there are spaces in the image name or URL's

you can either do this

```
isRemoteEnabled: true
```

or

```
$image = Image name.jpg; (causing error)
$image = Image%20name.jpg; (is okay)
```

So replace the image-name, which have spaces in it with %20 it will be solved.

```
$image = str_replace(' ', '%20', $items->image);
```